# I'm having trouble accessing the value I need from an NSDictionary object

Tags: objective-c

I'm having trouble accessing the value I need in an NSDictionary object, a song has multiple values under the track key, but since dictionaries aren't indexable, I'm unable to access the values individually. I have tried storing the object for the track key as an array but the two entries become a single string entry and therefore the array is only of length 1 and not helpful.

Also, doing something like [response valueForKeyPath@"response.songs.tracks.foreign_id"] gives me both foreign ids, how can I just get the first one? I've been struggling with this for a while, have searched all around stackoverflow for answers but none have worked, any help is appreciated, thanks!

This is the data in the NSDictionary:

```
{
    response = {
        songs = (
                    {
            "artist_foreign_ids" =                 (
                                    {
                    catalog = spotify;
                    "foreign_id" = "spotify:artist:6vWDO969PvNqNYHIOW5v0m";
                }
            );
            "artist_id" = AR65K7A1187FB4DAA4;
            "artist_name" = "Beyonc\U00e9";
            id = SOUTJIT142F256C3B5;
            title = "Partition (Explicit Version)";
            tracks =                 (
                                    {
                    catalog = spotify;
                    "foreign_id" = "spotify:track:2vPTtiR7x7T6Lr17CE2FAE"; //I WANT TO ACCESS JUST THIS VALUE
                    "foreign_release_id" = "spotify:album:1hq4Vrcbua3DDBLhuWFEVQ";
                    id = TRLHJRD1460052F846;
                },
                                    {
                    catalog = spotify;
                    "foreign_id" = "spotify:track:6m4ZFQb3zPt3IdRDTN3tfb";
                    "foreign_release_id" = "spotify:album:5KPpho7rztJrZVA9yXjk8K";
                    id = TRYMBSK146005C3A46;
                }
            );
        }
    );
       status =         {
           code = 0;
           message = Success;
           version = "4.2";
       };
   };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tracks` in your sample dictionary appear to already be an array (of dictionaries), so you should be able to do something like:

```
NSArray *songs = response[@"songs"];
for (NSDictionary *songDict in songs) {
    NSArray *tracks = songDict[@"tracks"];
    for (NSDictionary *trackDict in tracks) {
        NSString *trackForeignId = trackDict[@"foreign_id"];
        // Do whatever you like with trackForeignId here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked great!